# Why does JavaScript print undefined when setTimeout is being used?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Consider:

```
(function(){
  console.log(1);
  setTimeout(function(){console.log(2)},1000);
  setTimeout(function(){console.log(3)},0);
  console.log(4);

 })();
```

The code written above outputs:

```
 1
 4
 undefined
 3
 2
```

What is happening behind the scene, as I can understand setTimeout function is delaying it by 1 sec
and 0 sec?

*Why* it is printing out undefined?

Comment: You seem to execute that code in the browser console which will log the result of the expressions you execute from there. `undefined` is the implicit return value of `(function(){/* ... */ })();`.

Comment: In your code snippet it never display

Comment: @NullPointer I rejected your edit because the question is to do with running the code in the browser console, not the code itself.  Adding a snippet would just lead to confusion as it does not behave the same as the browser console.

Comment: @shreyas-ok got it. Thanks